# concatenate strings in specific columns of data frame

Tags: r

I tried to combine the two strings in the column `Patient_ID`, but my output did not format as a column. What is wrong?

```
 > head(Clinical)
  Patient_ID Preoperative_treat Metastasis Cancer_origin Type_of_tumor Recurrence
1       1 JH                  0          0             1             0          0
2      9 KPH                  0          0             0             0          0
3    11A PAK                  0          0             0             0          0
4      14 KS                  0          1             0             0          1
5    15 REMB                  0          0             0            NA          0
6      88 BS                  1          0             0             0          0


Clinical$Patient_ID <- paste(Clinical$Patient_ID, collapse="_")
```

Comment: You're just trying to replace the space with an underscore? Just use `gsub`....

Comment: gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "_", x = Clinical$Patient_ID )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll offer an explanation of why what you tried doesn't work. It's easiest to see when `Patient_ID` is the only column in `Clinical`.

```
Clinical <- data.frame(Patient_ID = c("1 JH", "9 KPH", "11A PAK", "14 KS", "15 REMB", "88 BS"))
Clinical
#   Patient_ID
# 1       1 JH
# 2      9 KPH
# 3    11A PAK
# 4      14 KS
# 5    15 REMB
# 6      88 BS
```

Each observation is a length-one character vector. Specifying `collapse = "_"` will concatenate them placing `_` between each *vector*, not in the text within the vectors.

```
paste(Clinical$Patient_ID, collapse = "_")
# [1] "1 JH_9 KPH_11A PAK_14 KS_15 REMB_88 BS"
```

Note the output is a length-one character vector.

Solution: as others said in the comments, use `gsub` to replace whitespace within text.

```
gsub("\\s", "_", Patient_ID$Clinical)
# [1] "1_JH"    "9_KPH"   "11A_PAK" "14_KS"   "15_REMB" "88_BS"
```